# Adding string to firstname for certain storeview in checkout?

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, billing-address

I am running **Magento 1.7.0.2** and I want to add a string to the firstname and lastname in the checkout.

My template is `template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`. The code there which seems to be responsible for rendering the firstname and lastname is:

```
<li class="fields"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($this->getAddress()->getFirstname() ? $this->getAddress() : $this->getQuote()->getCustomer())->setForceUseCustomerRequiredAttributes(!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn())->setFieldIdFormat('billing:%s')->setFieldNameFormat('billing[%s]')->toHtml() ?></li>
```

I also know how to make it only for a certain storeview, but I do not know where ... so, any advice on where I would do that?

Thanks